# how to check if a Product is in his last expiration week using Date class

Tags: java, date

i got a class "Product" which has a Date variable that represents the expiration date, now i want to check if the product is in the last expiration week.
All i could do is manage to see if the date is before or after the expiration date but i want to know precisely how many days, to check if it falls in the last week

```
...
Date dv = new Date();
if (dv.after(vexp))
    return false;
else
    return true; }
...
```

how can i change this portion of my code to get it working?

EDIT sry i meant "week" as 7 days so i need to check if it is in the last 7 days of expiration date

Comment: What do you mean by last week? Do you consider 6 days before the expiration date as in that week? Or, if the expiration date is on wednesday, and only check from Monday to Wednesday?

Comment: yes i meant 6 days before the exp date counting it as a "week" (7 days) without caring about the particular day positioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code determines whether expiration is within the last 7 days.

```
static final int ONE_DAY_MILLIS = 86400 * 1000;
//....
long deltaMillis = vexp.getTime() - dv.getTime();
if (deltaMillis < 7 * ONE_DAY_MILLIS) {
  // within last 7 days
}
```